# Is static code always executed when we use a class for the first time?

Tags: java, static, jvm, final

Our application is using initialization code that depends on the order static code is executed and I'm wondering if this order will be consistent across all JVMs.

Here is a sample of what I mean:

```
public class Main {

    static String staticVar = "init_value";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(A.staticVar);
        staticVar = "mainValue";
        System.out.println(A.staticVar);
    }
}

public class A {
    static String staticVar = Main.staticVar;
}
```

will give:

```
init_value
init_value
```

and

```
public class Main {

    static String staticVar = "init_value";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // System.out.println(A.staticVar);
        staticVar = "mainValue";
        System.out.println(A.staticVar);
    }
}

public class A {
    static String staticVar = Main.staticVar;
}
```

will give (on my environment):

```
mainValue
```

To summarize, across all JVMs, is static code always executed when we use a class for the first time?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

EDIT: Despite all the reassurances below, if you're thinking of relying on this sort of thing, I would try hard to refactor your code so that it doesn't crop up. While it *is* guaranteed to work, it's also likely to make your code very brittle. The fact that static initializers get called "invisibly" makes them relatively hard to reason about and debug.

---

Yes, this is guaranteed by the language specification. From [section 8.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.7Blockquote) of the spec:

> Any static initializers declared in a class are executed when the class is initialized and, together with any field initializers (§8.3.2) for class variables, may be used to initialize the class variables of the class (§12.4).
>
> StaticInitializer:  `static` *Block*
>
> It is a compile-time error for a static initializer to be able to complete abruptly (§14.1, §15.6) with a checked exception (§11.2). It is a compile-time error if a static initializer cannot complete normally (§14.21).
>
> The static initializers and class variable initializers are executed in textual order.

And from [section 12.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.4):

> Initialization of a class consists of
>   executing its static initializers and
>   the initializers for static fields
>   declared in the class. Initialization
>   of an interface consists of executing
>   the initializers for fields declared
>   in the interface.
>
> Before a class is
>   initialized, its direct superclass
>   must be initialized, but interfaces
>   implemented by the class need not be
>   initialized. Similarly, the
>   superinterfaces of an interface need
>   not be initialized before the
>   interface is initialized.
>
> A class or interface type T will be
>   initialized immediately before the
>   first occurrence of any one of the
>   following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is
>     created.
> - T is a class and a static
>     method declared by T is invoked.
> - A
>     static field declared by T is
>     assigned.
> - A static field declared by T
>     is used and the field is not a
>     constant variable (§4.12.4).
> - T is a
>     top-level class, and an assert
>     statement (§14.10) lexically nested

Comment: How is it that accepted answer is always coming from Jon? ;) Looks like he has some kind of unfair advantage on this site ;)

Answer (score 4):

Static initialisers (e.g. your staticVar declarations) are always executed when you use a class for the first time.

Static methods are only executed when they are called. In your case, this is happening because the static void main(String[] args) is the entry point to your application. But if you defined a different static method then it would not be called.

It is also possible to create a static initialiser block that will also be called automatically before the class is first used, e.g.

```
static {
  // some initialisation code here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That should be all the same on all platforms. See JVM Specification : http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Concepts.doc.html#19075

Answer (score 2):

A quote from Java specification:

> Initialization of a **class** consists of
>   executing its static initializers and
>   the initializers for static fields
>   declared in the class. Initialization
>   of an interface consists of executing
>   the initializers for fields declared
>   in the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.7) static code is always executed in the same order on all (compliant) JVM's.

[8.7 Static Initializers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.7)

> The static initializers and class variable initializers are executed in textual order.

Comment: That shows the order within the static initializers - but it doesn't answer as to whether the code is always executed when a class is used.

Answer (score 1):

Dittos to other posters, but let me add that a static initializer that depends on the state of other classes like in your example seems to me to make for very fragile and difficult-to-maintain code. I'll use static intializers to populate internal class data -- to fill up an array with default values or that sort of thing. But I don't think I've ever had one peek at the data in another class. Technically legal, and maybe there are odd cases where it's a good idea, but yuck.

Comment: +1 for yuck... IMO such an initializer is (only) a good idea to see/show when it is called.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe that would be the point by definition.

Answer (score 0):

**Static Block will always run first not just the first time**... Before executing any code block, `JVM execute the static code block first`, and then only it run the code block as it has been designed...